# Mysql Syntax Error with CONCATs

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Hey guys I'm getting a syntax error on my CONCATS for some reason, 
this is very weird since its pretty much a copy/paste from another
one of my queries using CONCATS that works flawlessly?

Here's the bad query

```
SELECT 
    brand, 
    case_count AS case, 
    variety, 
    style, 
    grower_lot AS lot, 
    pack_date AS date, 
    CONCAT(berry_size1, "-", berry_size2, "/", berry_size3, "-", berry_size4) AS size, 
    CONCAT(color1, "-", color2) AS color, 
    CONCAT(stem1, "-", stem2, "-", stem3) AS stem_cndt, 
    CONCAT(bunch_count1, "-", bunch_count2, "-", bunch_count3) AS bnch_cnt, 
    CONCAT(shatter1, "-", shatter2) AS shatter, 
    CONCAT(splits1, "-", splits2) AS split, 
    CONCAT(decay_count1, "-", decay_count2) AS decay, 
    CONCAT(wet_sticky1, "-", wet_sticky2) AS wet_sticky, 
    overall_quality AS quality, 
    CONCAT(sugar_brix1, "-", sugar_brix2) brix, 
    overall_condition AS condition, 
    rating, 
    inspector AS insp, 
    comments 
FROM `lot`
```

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case, variety, style, grower_lot AS lot, pack_date AS date, ' at line 3**

And here's one that seems to work

```
SELECT
        shipper, 
        po, 
        commodity as comm, 
        count, 
        size, 
        label, 
        variety, 
        pack_date AS date, 
        grower_lot AS lot, 
        CONCAT(color1, "-", color2) AS color, 
        CONCAT(sizing1, "-", sizing2, " / ", "sizing3", "-", sizing4 ) AS size, 
        CONCAT(firmness1, "-", firmness2) AS firmness, 
        CONCAT(scars_count1, "-", scars_count2) AS scars, 
        CONCAT(bruise_count2, "-", bruise_count2) AS bruise, 
        CONCAT(decay_count1, "-", decay_count2) AS decay_cnt, 
        CONCAT(sugar_brix1, "-", sugar_brix2) brix, 
        rating, 
        inspector AS insp, 
        comments
FROM `berries`
```

Comment: Please paste the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an issue with `CONCAT` per se, but `case` is a reserved word in MySQL, and needs to be backtick-escaped.

Comment: After changing case to case_cnt I get the error **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition, rating, inspector AS insp, comments FROM `lot` LIMIT 0, ' at line 18**

Comment: Unfortunately, `condition` is another reserved word.  @Mchl's response links to the full list of reserved words.

Comment: Yep that was it, just seem to be using all the reserved words today =P

Answer (score 1):

`case` is MySQL's reserved word. You need to put it within backticks, if you want to use it as column alias.

Full list of reserved words available here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html